# where can I find a neo4j quick tutorial?

Tags: database, neo4j, graph-databases

I was trying to save directed graphs into databases for further processing and query. And neo4j seems to fit my needs. However, I don't seem to find a good tutorial regarding the following:

- Creating the database and put data in.
- Making queries.

I want to be able to do them both manually and automatically (i.e. using a program). The official manual keeps talking about stuff like Maven, Index, REST API and so on, basically things I don't care about at all for now.

So any good hands-on tutorial on neo4j? Or any other graph databases you think is good for total beginners with simple needs (i.e. store graph and query graph)?

Comment: What Programming language are you using?

Comment: Please direct your question to the Neo4j google group http://neo4j.org/forums

Comment: Its too late but still a good option : http://bit.ly/1qyCKnd

Comment: Can find good Neo4j tutorials along with videos-http://www.javainuse.com/nosql/neo4j_tutorials

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For getting started just [download](http://neo4j.org/download) the Neo4j Server and start it. Then go to http://localhost:7474 for the integrated web-admin UI which allows you to enter data visually and browser/visualize and query it.

Please have a look at the [Neo4j Koans](https://github.com/jimwebber/neo4j-tutorial) by Jim Webber and Ian Robinson which are material that are used in real-world tutorials. Otherwise also have a look on http://video.neo4j.org for some screencasts and presentations and the collection of [introduction links](http://www.delicious.com/neo4j/introduction) at the neo4j delicious site.

Answer (score 10):

I started a [blog](http://maxdemarzi.com) for Neo4j beginners.  The first four posts are up and they show you how to [get neo4j](http://maxdemarzi.com/2012/01/04/getting-started-with-ruby-and-neo4j/), install it, create some sample data, find friends of friends, six degrees of separation (path finding), use gremlin scripts and cypher queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link to your blog.I am a beginner in neo4j and really love your stuff.

Answer (score 5):

Try http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/tutorials-java-embedded.html or http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/ for more tutorials. Does that work?

Comment: try http://weblog4j.com/2013/07/22/neo4j-a-next-generation-graph-database-and-java/