# Neo4J first steps: how to code the most basic operations

Tags: neo4j

I have just installed Neo4J, is up and running beautifully. I am looking for a very simple tutorial (few command lines actually) where I will be able to:

1. Create some data (at least 2 nodes and one relation between them);
2. Query and see the data recently created;
3. Update properties of this sample data;
4. Delete the created data;
   The sample code can be in Cypher and/or Gremlin, to run in the web admin console, in the default empty database.

I have looked a lot on the official site, its docs, books and tutorials and they all seem to be quite complex: some even drive me to create an Java application (I don't even work with Java). Just like a SQL beginner, I want to test the most basic database operations, from the most basic interface, the admin panel. Don't understand why, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623080/where-can-i-find-a-neo4j-quick-tutorial) has been closed for not being constructive (!?).

thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: To add to the answers, check out the online cypher tutorial: http://neo4j.org/learn/cypher Would love to get some feedback from your about it.

Comment: Your tutorial only works for a given already-filled database (movies). I want something more basic. Besides, some code did not work with the same database in my localhost.

Comment: The tutorial includes a sandbox console that is already filled. You can duplicate that setup by executing the create statement shown as "Graph Setup" when you scroll up. Can yo u be more specific on what didn't work?

Comment: Is my question that hard? Insert, select, update and delete in Cypher, Gremlyn or Sparql to be written on my own command line, in the default out-of-box empty database. Don'want to install movies or wahtever-gdb,  dnot using a online sandbox, don't want to watch webminars, don't want to read an entire book. **Four working command lines that work in my brand new Neo4J Enterprise setup**, as simple as it sounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE ( blagus  { firstname: 'Alexander', lastname: 'Blagus'} )

CREATE (celso  { firstname: 'Celso', lastname: 'Oliveira'}), (celso) - [r:WORKS_WITH] - > (blagus)

return blagus, celso, r
```

In this example there are 2 distinct queries, the first one creates a node with 2 properties. The second one does the exact same thing as the first one plus creates a relationships from celso to blagus

```
START n=node(*) RETURN "The number of nodes in your graph is "+count(*)+" !" as total;
```

Returns a variable named total with the value 'The number of nodes in your graph is 2!', it´s basically the same as select count(*)

```
START me=node(1) MATCH me<--friend
RETURN friend
```

Assuming we are using this simple database as example, this would return the node celso considering the direction of the relationship

```
  START n=node(*)
    MATCH n
    WHERE n.firstname! ='Alexander'
    RETURN n
```

This query matches all nodes with the property firstname equals to Alexander. Please note that the “!” symbol make sures that only the nodes which have such property are going to be taken into consideration, preventing an error.

```
START n=node(*)
MATCH n
WHERE n.firstname! ='Alexander'
SET n.age = '34'
RETURN n
```

This query matches the node which has the property firstname Alexander and adds another property "age" with the value "34"

```
START n = node(*)
MATCH n WHERE n.firstname! = "Geraldo" DELETE n
```

This query matches all nodes with the firstname equals to "Geraldo" and deletes them.

```
START n = node(*)
MATCH n-[r]-()
DELETE n, r
```

This command gets all nodes and relationships and deletes them.

Hope it Helps!

Comment: It does helps! There are a very few statments that did not work, syntax maybe? Or my Neo4J version.

Answer (score 2):

A very short version of things would be:

```
create ({name:"alice"})-[:likes]->({name:"bob"});

match n-[r]->m return n,r,m;

match alice where alice.name! = 'alice' set alice.lastname='Alison';

match alice where alice.lastname! = 'Alison' return alice;

match n-[r]->m delete r,n,m;
```

This is all using the syntax of neo4j 2.0.0M3.

There is the free [graph databases](http://graphdatabases.com) book, which contains a nice introduction into cypher. The examples as printed in the book don't work out of the box. I've put [working examples](https://baach.de/Members/jhb/working-examples-for-the-graph-databases-book/) online. And of course, there is [more on the neo4j website](http://neo4j.org/learn/cypher).

Comment: Thanks Joerg, I just spaced out your queries. Perhaps add the http://neo4j.org/learn/cypher link.

Comment: The first line worked, the match ones I got an error: "Unknown command 'match'". I've tryed some examples from the book, like the Shakespeare; some commands did work, but most not (I won't enter in details as soon this is not the scope of this thread). The Neo4J does not provide a simple quick start tutorial, one must go throught a lot of theory before doing anything practical.  I'll take a look at working examples link, thank you!

Comment: I think you might be using a 'stable' version of neo4j, 1.9.x. Using the syntax above ('match') requires version 2.x, a.k.a milestone (as mentioned below my examples)

Comment: Yes, this is it. Would be possible to create an code compatible with the stable version? Appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of great resources [here](http://www.neo4j.org/learn) - especially the free book. Haven't used this, but it looks like it might be helpful - basically learning Neo4j through fixing broken tests: [Neo4j-tutorial](https://github.com/jimwebber/neo4j-tutorial)

Comment: The book is great, I'll print it out and read all. But, as mentioned before, no place, including your links have a quick start tutorial. The first link pointing to Neo4J site goes throught a looot theory, I just want to get started inserting, selecting, updating and deleting data. If you have a link with that 4 simple lines, I will appreciate. The second link points out to an Java application that I have to download, configure and install; I mentioned it in the bottom of my question: I don't even work with Java. I'm talking about Neo4J only.